Set value in column based on multiple conditions on multiple columns
Could someone please help me on this.
Been searching for hours on several platforms, tried several solutions but can't figure out the exact code for the possible solutions. In other words: I can't get my job done.
Challenge: I want to put a text in my column "Reason": the reason(s) why the record in my "problem list").
But this text is depending on the values in different columns and (where applicable) is build up from several texts and (this is maybe the tricky part) I'd like to have a carriage return between these texts). In the table underneath No. SO1237 and SO1238.
Usually I only have select statements, with or whithout nested select statements with inner of left outer joins, all that is pretty clear to me.
Also I'm familiar with getting my data in a temp table.
Example data:



No.
Description
Kind
Type
Completed
Reason




SO1234
[Description of SO1234]
Sport
Medior
TRUE



SO1235

Music
Junior
TRUE
Description is empty


SO1236
[Description of SO1236]

Senior
TRUE
Kind is empty


SO1237
[Description of SO1237]


TRUE
Kind is empty







Type is empty


SO1238
[Description of SO1238]
Literature

FALSE
Type is empty







Completed is false



The data in the columns No., Description, Kind, Type and Completed comes from a select statement with an inner join to another table.
What is the best way to fix this?
Should/can I get these texts in my column Reason directly with the select statement?
I would say it's easier to first get it in a temp table, so the number of records is a lot smaller and so performance is a far less risk. Subsequently I would think to do something with a cursor to loop through the records in my temp table, but I don't know how I have to fix the building of the text string in the column Reason.
The number of columns to be checked is in the example above 4, but this is expected to increase, so the code should be modified as easy as possible.
I hope someone can help me on this.
Many thanks in advance.
I tried to use code with case when statements in the select from statement, but that is getting to complicated. Too much options/combinations are possible.
I also tried to wright code with a cursur, but I can't figure out the syntax of that.
I want a text in my column Reason that is consists of different text strings that (depending of the combination of found errors) can be empty or contains 1, 2, 3 or 4 text strings.
So for based on the checks that are done, the records can have text strings a, a+b, a+c, a+b+c, a+d, etc.

Why is the case statement getting so complicated, you should only need one condition per column. Should the result for SO1237, be "Kind is empty. Type is empty." Why is "Type" the only reason for the totally empty row, is there some kind of precedence rule? In any case, this strikes me as more of a data model problem. Maybe Reason doesn't really belong in this table and should be derived elsewhere.

You'd better add a tag for the dbms used. Don't waste people's time writing product specific answer for 'wrong' dbms.

@Error_2646: Sorry for the misunderstanding. While writing the text, it wasn't clear to me how I should place the pipes to get the two lines in once call after placing the question and the conversion by the website.
To Error_2646 and and jarlh: I know that this is not what dba's expect to be done in a database. But if you don't know the situation and motivation, please temper your comment.

You can construct the reason column from a series of concatonated case expressions. Use + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) for line breaks. Here is a SQL-Server solution:
SELECT *, 
     TRIM(CASE Description WHEN '' THEN 'Description is empty'  + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) ELSE '' END 
    +CASE Kind WHEN '' THEN 'Kind is empty'  + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) ELSE '' END 
    +CASE Type WHEN '' THEN 'Type is empty'  + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) ELSE '' END 
    +CASE Completed WHEN 'False' THEN 'Completed is false'  + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) ELSE '' END)  as
     CalculatedReason
FROM ProblemList

fiddle

Note that this is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. And case is an expression.

@jarlh thanks for the suggestions. I have made some corrections.

Hi fiddle, thanks for your effort!!!
